# tab layout text is being cut off in small screen sizes

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I am using tab layout with custom views.

The issues I am facing are the following  -

1) The text is being cut off with small screen devices as you can see here -

small device -

[image]

big device -

[image]

2) the second issue I am facing is as you can see, the background does not go `wrap content` on "Chats" tabs. It does through wrap the "Market" tab title as it is longer. I need it to wrap quallity with short and long texts.

here is my xml -

```xml
  <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/activity_dashboard_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/transparent">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:src="@drawable/user_default_image"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/black"
            app:civ_border_width="1dp" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_dashboard_tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_dashboard_toolbar"
        app:tabIndicator="@null" />

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/activity_dashboard_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_dashboard_tablayout" />
```

```kotlin
 private fun initTabLayoutAndViewPager() {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        supportActionBar?.title = null
        viewpager.adapter = DashboardViewPagerAdapter(this)
        TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewpager, TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy { _, _ -> }).attach()

        val chatsView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.dashboard_activity_cusom_tab, null)
        val callsView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.dashboard_activity_cusom_tab, null)
        val walletView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.dashboard_activity_cusom_tab, null)
        val marketView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.dashboard_activity_cusom_tab, null)

        (chatsView as TextView).text = pageTitles[0]
        (callsView as TextView).text = pageTitles[1]
        (walletView as TextView).text = pageTitles[2]
        (marketView as TextView).text = pageTitles[3]

        chatTextView = chatsView
        callsTextView = callsView
        walletTextView = walletView
        marketTextView = marketView


        tabLayout.getTabAt(0)?.customView = chatTextView
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1)?.customView = callsTextView
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2)?.customView = walletTextView
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3)?.customView = marketTextView

        viewpager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {

            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                super.onPageSelected(position)
                when(position) {

                    DashboardTabs.CHATS.type -> {
                        ViewPagerUtils.setSelectedTab(chatTextView, callsView, walletView, marketView)
                    }
                    DashboardTabs.CALLS.type -> {
                        ViewPagerUtils.setSelectedTab(callsView, chatTextView, walletView, marketView)
                    }
                    DashboardTabs.WALLET.type -> {
                        ViewPagerUtils.setSelectedTab(walletView, callsView, chatTextView, marketView)
                    }
                    DashboardTabs.MARKET.type -> {
                        ViewPagerUtils.setSelectedTab(marketView, callsView, walletView, chatTextView)
                    }

                }
            }
        })
    }
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
    android:paddingStart="5dp"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    tools:text="Chats">

</TextView>
```

edit -

After resolving the issue with the answer provided here I am stuck a gravity issue -

[image]

how can I make all tabs in the center? tried both `gravity` and `layout_gravity` and none helped me.

Comment: make tab layout mode scrolleable

Comment: app:tabMode="scrollable"

Comment: please add it as comment and I will approve. works like a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make tab layout mode scrollable `app:tabMode="scrollable"` or `app:tabMode="auto"` like below

```
 <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_dashboard_tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_dashboard_toolbar"
        app:tabIndicator="@null" />
```

Comment: I have now one more issue please - the gravity of the entire tab layout is set to the start. How do I make it center again?

Comment: android:layout_gravity="center"

Comment: in this one in tab layout

Comment: just tried that, did not work. please check my edit at the main post so you can see the issue

Comment: tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

Comment: when setting to "scrollable" it starts the scrolling from START position of the view. I need the entire tab view to be centered width with the "scrollable" side effects (long texts and wrapping background)

Comment: sets `tabMaxWidth="0dp"`, `tabGravity="fill"` and `tabMode="fixed"`.

Comment: I used `app:tabMode="auto"` and it fixed my issue. Thanks!

Comment: along with `tabMaxWidth="0dp"`, `tabGravity="fill"`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210726/discussion-between-alon-shlider-and-nensi-kasundra).